# How to open a .tsv file in Jupyter? Jupyter.Notebook tried suggestions, but it doesn't work

Tags: pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

How can I open a `.tsv` file in Jupyter.
The data is stored under `C:/User/anna/`.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('C:/User/anna/train')
```

But I get this error message:

> FileNotFoundError: File b'C:/Users/anna/train.txt' does not exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's actually to do with pandas, by default the separator is comma, not tab.
try the code below:

```
df=pd.read_csv('C:/User/anna/train', sep='\t')
```

Answer (score 0):

it sounds lame, but finally i opened it - my first attempt to open anything in anaconda.: )

thanks.

```
df=pd.read_csv('C:/User/anna/train.tsv',sep='\t')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're opening .tsv file from your local, please attempt the below code:

import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv(r'c:\User\anna\train.tsv', sep='\t')

print(df)